# How to easily convert Debian script to RPM script?

Tags: scripting, centos, debian, redhat, rpm

I'm aiming to ***translate*** a Debian package to an RPM package to install it on a CentOS Linux 7 (Red Hat).
I used `alien` to accomplish it: `alien --to-rpm --scripts --keep-version debian_pkg.deb`. However, when I want to install the created rpm package, an error is raised from the `preinst` script. I saw online that there is a high likelihood that scripts written for Debian packages won’t work for RPM packages.

Is there an easy way to translate a Debian script to an RPM script? If not, is there any common patterns when you want to do the conversion?

Thanks!

Comment: This looks very much like a duplicate -- I know I answered a very similar question recently, but I can't find it now. Was it yours as well?

Comment: I've asked this question on February 1st, so maybe it was already this post. Nevertheless, it's the only post I made concerning alien and package conversion.

Comment: Not yours then, I'll see if I can find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I learned it through the process, there is no easy way to translate a Debian package to an RPM package. You need to go through your scripts and translate them manually. To do so, you need to execute `alien --to-rpm --scripts --generate debian_pkg.deb`, it creates a temporary directory suitable for building a package from. You find your scripts inside the `.spec` file. If somebody encounters this problem, here is some documentation that helped me a lot: [RPM Packaging guide](https://rpm-packaging-guide.github.io/#packaging-software) and [Building and distributing packages](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-rpm1/index.html?ca=drs-).